# How to fix ahref not linking to the id

Tags: html, tags

I'm creating a table of contents using the id linking method. How do I get it to work properly? I've triple checked and for some reason, it's not responding when I click on the link.

I've tried creating an id and name within the tag. It only seems to work for the top of page id. I'm using Shopify's blog editing feature which accepts HTML.

```
<a href="#Test">1. Example</a>    

<h3 id="Test">My Header Here</h3>
```

I've got it to work before but it's not anymore. Maybe I have to clear my cache?

Answer (score 0):

you just add height at your  tag

for example

```
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <div style="height:600px">
        <a href="#Test">1. Example</a>
    </div>
    <div style="height:600px">
            <h3 id="Test">My Header Here</h3>
        </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Are you saying there has to be more space in between? Not following. This just created a big gap.

Answer (score 0):

The code is correct.
What happens if you try the code below instead? Both of these should be valid, so it would be weird that one works and the other doesn't.

```
<a href="#Test">1. Example</a> 
<a name="Test"><h3>My Header Here</h3></a>
```

Comment: Your right, I think its because im in preview mode of the blog. ill publish and see what happens. I got a few links working but some do not.